# ERROR: cannot launch node of type [controller_manager/controller_manager]: can't locate node [controller_manager] in package [controller_manager]

Tags: ros, ur10, controller-manager

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all. I installed the university_robot package and `roslaunch ur_gazebo ur10.launch` but  there is an error output:

```
`ERROR: cannot launch node of type [controller_manager/controller_manager]: can't locate node [controller_manager] in package [controller_manager]

ERROR: cannot launch node of type [controller_manager/controller_manager]: can't locate node [controller_manager] in package [controller_manager]
```

`I run`rosservice list | grep controller_manager` the output is

```
`/controller_manager/list_controller_types
/controller_manager/list_controllers
/controller_manager/load_controller
/controller_manager/reload_controller_libraries
/controller_manager/switch_controller
/controller_manager/unload_controller
```

`I have installed the controller_manager. Could someone give me some advice?Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/276507/error:-cannot-launch-node-of-type-%5Bcontroller_manager/controller_manager%5D:-can%27t-locate-node-%5Bcontroller_manager%5D-in-package-%5Bcontroller_manager%5D/) by [tengfei](https://answers.ros.org/users/31490/tengfei/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2017-11-22

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-23**:\

> I installed the university_robot package [..]

the first thing would be for you to tell us how you installed it.

The error message seems to indicate that some dependencies are missing, which should only happen if you did a from-sources installation (ie: not used the `.deb`s).

**Comment by [tengfei](https://answers.ros.org/users/31490/tengfei/) on 2017-11-23**:
Thanks gvdhoorn. I have solved this problem. In my catkin_ws/src, there is a ros_control package contains nothing in it.I don't why when I use `rosrun` and use the tab can make the full name with control_manager. I removed all the packages related ros_control and reinstalled them then it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have solved this problem. In my catkin_ws/src, there is a ros_control package contains nothing in it.And I have installed ros_control by `rosrun apt-get install ros-indigo-ros-control`,I guess the ros will first search the package in catkin_ws/src.If there is no this package,it will search the package in /opt/ros/,I don't why when I use rosrun and use the tab can make the full name with control_manager. But I guess this is the reason that why ros can't locate node [controller_manager] in package . So I removed all the packages related ros_control and reinstalled them, then it works.

---

Originally posted by [tengfei](https://answers.ros.org/users/31490/tengfei/) with karma: 88 on 2017-11-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4